# Strange STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED issue with SMB2 client and Freenas CIFS SHARE

Tags: samba, server-message-block, cifs, truenas, samba4

I've recently started seeing some strange SMB2 Errors on Windows 10 PCs (all of them version 1903).

The Fileserver is running FreeNAS-11.1-U7 (with ZFS Volumes) and CIFS Shares with Active Directory ACL.

When I open some images from Adobe Bridge or even Windows Explorer, I don't see any errors on the user interface but Wireshark shows a SMB2 STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED error.

But I can see the images on the Explorer or Adobe Bridge. Additionally, similar images with identical permissions DON'T show any errors as below.

Here's the full conversation packets:

```
86492   0.000127    192.168.0.242   192.168.0.46    SMB2    162 GetInfo Request SEC_INFO/SMB2_SEC_INFO_00 File: CLIENT FOLDER\200_JO\200_Selects\200_1330.CR2


86491   0.000266    192.168.0.46    192.168.0.242   SMB2    374 Create Response File: CLIENT FOLDER\200_JO\200_Selects\200_1330.CR2
```

I've looked up SMB2's documentation and there's nothing that explains this type of error. Specially the SMB2_SEC_INFO_00 request by client.

Comment: I've the same "issue" on a pure Windows environment. Client and Server is Windows Server 2016 and my log shows many SMB2_SEC_INFO_00 denied with STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED. Currently I can't see any influence for the user

Comment: Have you ever found a solution or explanation to this ? @arpan

Comment: I have this error too and want to know more. +1